# Does expl3 have alternative to \settowidth and \settoheight?

Tags: expl3, latex3, lengths

How can I substitute following code with `expl3` interfaces (that do the same job)?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \newlength\spaceWidth
  \settowidth{\spaceWidth}{\ }
  \the\spaceWidth
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question title is about measuring boxes but if your actual goal is the example in the code then this is a very inefficient way to find the width of a space, that width is already available as a tex length it is fontdimen 2 of the current font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing equivalent (that I know of), but you can implement your own (and by *implement* I mean copy from `latex.ltx` and change the syntax). I defined `\SetToHeight`, `\SetToWidth`, and `\SetToDepth`, that do the same as the LaTeX2e's variants.

However, for the specific case of a space, you can use `\fontdimen2\font`, which will get the width of a space in the current font without the need to measure a box, thus it is expandable, so you can use in dimension expressions. I defined an `expl3`*y* wrapper for that as well:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_bp_set_to_box
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bp_box_set_to:NNn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_bp_set_to_box {#3}
    \dim_set:Nn #2 { #1 \l_bp_set_to_box }
    \box_set_eq:NN \l_bp_set_to_box \c_empty_box
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bp_set_to_height:Nn { \bp_box_set_to:NNn \box_ht:N }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bp_set_to_depth:Nn  { \bp_box_set_to:NNn \box_dp:N }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bp_set_to_width:Nn  { \bp_box_set_to:NNn \box_wd:N }
% Expandable width of a space:
\cs_new:Npn \WidthOfSpace { \tex_fontdimen:D 2 \tex_font:D }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \dim_new:N \spaceWidth
  \bp_set_to_width:Nn \spaceWidth {\ }
  \dim_use:N \spaceWidth
  \par
  \dim_use:N \WidthOfSpace
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

Comment: Why `\__`? These would need to be public

Comment: I wouldn't use `\l_tmpa_box`.

Comment: @JosephWright Only the `\SetToSomething`, no? Why does `\__bp_box_set_to:NNn` need to be public?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Because of the document/code level split: all document commands should be defined in terms of documented code-level ones.

Comment: @JosephWright Oh, okay. I thought the separation was "a user should/should not use this". Also following LaTeX2e's counterpart, `\@settodim`, has an `@` in the name.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Model is: document command defines user interface, this is implemented by code-level commands which start `\module_...` (so should be documented), and then they can use `\__module...` commands which are internal and thus 'no use'.

Answer (score 3):

```
\coffin_new:N\spaceCoffin
\hcoffin_set:Nn\spaceCoffin{\ }
% space width
\dim_eval:n{\coffin_wd:N\spaceCoffin}
```

---

```
\box_new:N\spaceBox
\hbox_set:Nn\spaceBox{\ }
% space width
\dim_eval:n{\box_wd:N\spaceBox}
```

Comment: You can, sure, use a coffin, however the computational overhead is much larger than for a simple box (as you edited in just now :-)